# Create a dockable window in Visio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, office-addins, visio

I created a Visio Add-In in Visual Studio 2022.
I need create a dockable window, however i can't see a way for create it.

Right now the only way I found was via a window form like:

```
myCustomForm = new Form();
myCustomForm.Text = "My (not) Integrated Window."
myCustomForm.Show();
```

but I'm not satisfied.

I also followed (without success) this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/office/vba/api/Visio.Windows.Add

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you point out in the question is the correct one. That is, you should use `Window.Windows.Add` to add dockable windows in Visio. Please share the issue you are facing when trying to use it.

There is also a project template (installable via Visual Studio "extensions" menu) with dockable window out of the box I've created many years ago, bit it should still be functional (i.e. works fine with VS2022 and the latest Visio version), you can check it out here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NikolayBelyh.ExtendedVisioAddinProject2017

If you decide to go with it, don't forget to give me a star :)

The source code is open on the GitHub (please check the above link for it)

Comment: wow! thank you! is exactly what I would like to implement... Unfortunately, I have tried both installing the add-in and running the code on github in visual studio 2022 with the latest version of the Visio plugin, but I cannot run it correctly.
do you think it should work correctly? sorry but I am new with this kink of projects and I am definitely doing some steps wrong.

Comment: Do you mean you follow this article? You need to install the extension in your Visual Studio, for the project to appear: https://unmanagedvisio.com/products/visual-studio-project-templates-to-create-visio-add-ins If you feel there is a bug, please go ahead and drop me an email directly (support@unmanagedvisio.com). Check the "getting started" chapter with the link above.

Comment: Please note that the project on github is VS extension itself, to use it you need to install VSIX (either from the visual studio marketplace, or directly form visual studio "extensions" menu, or from GitHub "releases") and then create new project of type "Extended Visio Add-In" that should appear in your "New Project" menu as a new project type.

Comment: It works! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to use winforms to open Visio directly, you can first drag a Button on Form1, then double-click the Button, and put the following code in the click event of the Button:

   ```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

         Process jcam = new Process();
         jcam.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Testnotepad.exe"; //The path to your Visio.exe
         ProcessStartInfo pr = jcam.StartInfo;
         pr.UseShellExecute = true;
         jcam.Start();
     }
   ```
2. If you want Visio to be displayed on the Form, first drag a paint onto the Form and set its dock to full (that is, the largest rectangle in the middle). code show as below:

   ```
    /// <summary>
    /// Embed external exe
    /// </summary>
    public class EmbeddedExeTool
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetParent")]
        private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "ShowWindow")]
        private static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
        IntPtr WindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        private const int WS_THICKFRAME = 262144;
        private const int WS_BORDER = 8388608;
        private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
        private const int WS_CAPTION = 0xC00000;
        private Process proApp = null;
        private Control ContainerControl = null;

        private const int WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr32(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtr", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr64(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

        private IntPtr SetWindowLong(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong) {
            if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
            {
                return SetWindowLongPtr32(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
            }
            return SetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Load an external exe program into the program container
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="control">To display the container control of the exe</param>
        /// <param name="exepath">The full absolute path of the exe</param>
        public void LoadEXE(Control control, string exepath) {
            ContainerControl = control;
            control.SizeChanged += Control_SizeChanged;
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(exepath);
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proApp = Process.Start(info);
            Application.Idle += Application_Idle;
            EmbedProcess(proApp, control);

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Load an external exe program into the program container
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="form">The form to display the exe</param>
        /// <param name="exepath">The full absolute path of the exe</param>
        public void LoadEXE(Form form, string exepath) {
            ContainerControl = form;
            form.SizeChanged += Control_SizeChanged;
            proApp = new Process();
            proApp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proApp.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proApp.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
            proApp.StartInfo.FileName = exepath;
            proApp.StartInfo.Arguments = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString();
            proApp.Start();
            Application.Idle += Application_Idle;
            EmbedProcess(proApp, form);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Make sure the application embeds this container
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (this.proApp == null || this.proApp.HasExited)
            {
                this.proApp = null;
                Application.Idle -= Application_Idle;
                return;
            }
            if (proApp.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero) return;
            Application.Idle -= Application_Idle;
            EmbedProcess(proApp, ContainerControl);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Embed the specified program into the specified control
        /// </summary>
        private void EmbedProcess(Process app, Control control) {
            // Get the main handle
            if (app == null || app.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero || control == null) return;
            try
            {
                // Put it into this form
                SetParent(app.MainWindowHandle, control.Handle);
                // Remove border and whatnot               
                SetWindowLong(new HandleRef(this, app.MainWindowHandle), GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE);
                ShowWindow(app.MainWindowHandle, (int)ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized);
                MoveWindow(app.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, control.Width, control.Height, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex3.Message);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Embed container resize event
        /// </summary>
        private void Control_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (proApp == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (proApp.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero && ContainerControl != null)
            {
                MoveWindow(proApp.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, ContainerControl.Width, ContainerControl.Height, true);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        EmbeddedExeTool exetool = new EmbeddedExeTool();

        exetool.LoadEXE(panel1, @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");  //The specific path to embed the external exe
        //Process jcam = new Process();
        //jcam.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Testnotepad.exe";  //The path to your Visio.exe
        //ProcessStartInfo pr = jcam.StartInfo;
        //pr.UseShellExecute = true;
        //jcam.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The dock of the panel needs to be set to full
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {


    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        EmbeddedExeTool exetool = new EmbeddedExeTool();

        exetool.LoadEXE(panel1, @"C:\Program Files\your.exe");  //The specific path to embed the external exe

    }
   ```

Comment: 'It sounds like you want to open Visio through winforms'. I hope this isn't an example of misunderstanding and code that an AI can drag up.

Comment: @PaulHerber AI can't write these codes, because I don't know Visio very well, so I added this sentence